# Flutter - FutureBuilder returns null snapshot, but the future is actually returning data

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to fetch data from an [API](https://spaceflightnewsapi.net/api/v1/reports?limit=1000?news_site=nasa?)

So i've used a Future to do so. The problem is: the future actually returns data from this API, because if I print those data it works, but when I retrieve the same data from snapshot it returns null.

That's the code for retrieving data:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class NasaReportsApi {
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final DateTime publishedDate;
  final Map<String, dynamic> general;

  NasaReportsApi({this.title, this.url, this.publishedDate, this.general});

  factory NasaReportsApi.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    // it actually print this with data
    print(json['docs'][0]['title']);
    //
    
    return NasaReportsApi(
      general: json['docs'],
      title: json['docs'][0]['title'],
      url: json['docs'][0]['url'],
      publishedDate: json['docs'][0]['published_date']
    );
  }
}

Future<NasaReportsApi> fetchReports() async {
  // try for network issues
  try {
    final response = await http
            .get("https://spaceflightnewsapi.net/api/v1/reports?limit=1000?news_site=nasa?");

    // status code 200 means the get request is successful
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return NasaReportsApi.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else
      throw Exception('Failed to load JSON');
  } catch (_) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

And that's my FutureBuilder:

```
 FutureBuilder<NasaReportsApi>(
    future: futureReports,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 1000,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  height: getHeight(context) / 20.0,
                  width: getWidth(context),
                  child: Card(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: getHeight(context) / 50.0,
                          left: getWidth(context) / 36.0,
                          right: getWidth(context) / 36.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                               snapshot.data.general[index]['title'],
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontSize: 17.0),
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
        );
      } else {
        return Container();
      }
    },
  ),
```

I didn't put the condition for when snapshot got no data to see what was happening. Printing `snapshot.error` simply print null. I've tried the same FutureBuilder with a similiar API and it works.

Answer (score 0):

To rely on `hasData` instead of connection state, will be better.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
        ...
}
```

Comment: as said in the question, even with the condition it doesn't works